# "modal form" with bootstrap on rails works partially

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

On Rails 3.2.3, 
I have a form in a partial view, using [bootstrap 2.0.2 modals](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

```
#myModal.modal
  .modal-header
    .close{"data-dismiss" => "modal"}= link_to "x", root_path
    %h3 Add Tags
  .modal-body
    = form_tag '/tagging', :remote => true do
      = text_field_tag 'tags_string', params[:tags_string]
      = hidden_field_tag 'id', params[:id]
      .modal-footer
        = submit_tag "Add tag", :class => "btn btn-primary"
  :javascript
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myModal .btn.btn-primary').click(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        $('form').submit();
      });
    });
```

I the "main" page I've a link button to call the partial :

```
%td= link_to "Tag", tagging_path(:id => "#{repo.id}", :tags_string => "#{repo.tags}"), "data-toggle" => "modal", :class => "tag add-tag btn btn-primary
```

and the controller has the relative tagging method.

Now I have two problems:

1. first

   when I click the button it display the form correctly but it leaves
   the "main" page (which I  don't want), displaing the relative href
   (which is empty), as a background :

   ```
   http://localhost:3001/tagging?id=4f82cb8ef370ff0001000699&tags_string=
   ```

   that is generated by the 'tagging_path' in the link button. I cannot
   just call the modal like in bootstrap example :

   ```
   <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a>
   ```

   because I need to fill the controller/model with form params so ...,
   how can this be done ?
2. second:

   when I click the "Add tag" button in the form, the database get the
   right content and everything works but the form doesn't disapear
   until I click "X" link, which is just a link to root_path and not a JS action.

   so it seems js is not working properly

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#myModal .btn.btn-primary').click(function() {
       $('#myModal').modal('hide');
       $('form').submit();
     });
   });
   ```

UPDATE:

This is the generated html :

```
<div class='modal hide fade' id='myModal'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
        <div class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><a href="/">x</a></div>
            <h3>Add Tags</h3>
        </div>

        <div class='modal-body'>
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/tagging" data-remote="true" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
                <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="vlZaCIRV58BfDZ0xjYsefSEVL1LSpiI5UL1tgzbm/8o=" /></div>
            <input id="tags_string" name="tags_string" type="text" />
            <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" />

            <div class='modal-footer'>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add tag" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<td>
    <a href="/tagging?id=4f82cb5cf370ff000100003a&amp;tags_string=ruby+web+framework" class="tag add-tag btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Tag</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <div class='gravatar'><img alt="Assets.github.com%2fimages%2fgravatars%2fgravatar-orgs" height="26" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/b0f9595244db739302ccce55bfbfc5e5?d=https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-orgs.png" width="26" /></div>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate">h5bp/html5-boilerplate</a>
</td>
<td class='watchers span1'>12105</td>
<td class='forks span1'>1781</td>
<td>A professional front-end template that helps you build fast, robust, adaptable, and future-proof websites.</td>
<td>Sun, Jan 24 at  6:03pm</td>
<td>Sat, Apr 14 at  2:10pm</td>

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the link action

2) Your selector needed a space.  Or you can just leave `.btn` out entirely.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal .btn-primary').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
```

If you post the *rendered* HTML markup of your modal I can help with your selector since using the class is generally not a good idea if you want to capture a specific button click.

**Edit given markup:**

Okay, you can just make your button a `button` type instead of `submit` and select it by its `name` instead.  If you use a `submit` you don't need to call `form.submit`, it does that by default.  Using a `button` type gives you more control.

```
$('input[name="commit"]').click(function() {
    //$('form').submit();
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');        
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tcjCj/3/